# Flot chart doesn't render

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, flot

I'm making a website using Visual Studio 2012 / ASP.NET MVC 4, and I would like to put a chart on the front page using Flot.

The project's BundleConfig is set up to include the entire Flot directory, and to include jQuery:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/flot").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/flot", "*.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

The scripts are rendered in the _Layout.cshtml file.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr", "~/bundles/jquery", "~bundles/flot")
```

The scripts are rendered again on the home page's View, and the flotcontainer div shows up on the home page but only as a blank rectangle.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr", "~/bundles/jquery", "~bundles/flot");
}

<div id="flotcontainer" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var oilPrices = [[1167692400000, 61.05] ...
        ...(Flot chart example goes here, nothing wrong with this part)...
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you checked the javascript console, what error did you see?

Comment: I see "TypeError: $.plot is not a function".

Comment: The error means flot is not being properly included.  Does the "home page View" use the layout (it doens't look like it from the code snip)?  If you view the source of your page, do you see an entry like: `<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=yLrUYw8wJsDVphfZd34hBbV8EDUqbXgqcJTvyPCUCRg1">` and `<script src="/bundles/flot?v=yLrUYw8wJsDVphfZd34hBbV8EDUqbXgqcJTvyPCUCRg1">`?  If you click those links do they both resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560142/flot-chart-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4#comment38042040_24560142) turned out to be correct - the problem was that "~bundles/flot" was missing a backslash, and it should have been written as "~/bundles/flot".  Thanks Mark!